# jQuery increase number depending on number of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6vxe8qyj/**

I've written a bit of script that adds a new attribute called `trackingID` that takes the title of each element and adds it into a tracking string.

The above works fine.

```
<a class="banner" title="This Is mainBanner 1"></a>
```

Would be:

```
<a class="banner" title="This Is mainBanner 1" trackingid="MAINBANNER-_-BANNER-_-This+Is+mainBanner+1"></a>
```

However, I've hit a bit of a bump as I'd like the **BANNER** section of the string to be numbered.  i.e. `BANNER+1` - `BANNER+2`

I then have a second set of banners (`#secBanners`) that I need to start back at 1 again.

I'm currently getting `undefined` and am unsure how to continue.

Any help would be great!

Thanks

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add the relevant script here; the demo is nice but it's a bonus, your question should be self-contained in order to guard against external sites falling over or otherwise going away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your current methodology of things ([EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6vxe8qyj/5/)):

#### JS

```
$('a').attr("trackingID", " ");

function tracking(element, attr, attrVal, track, i) {
    track.each(function () {
        var $this = $(this),
            trackRegEx,
            newVal = attrVal.replace(/\[intBanner\]/g, i);

        $this.attr(attr, newVal);

        if ($this.attr('title') !== undefined && $this.attr('title') !== '') {
            trackRegEx = $this.attr('title').replace(/ /g, '+');
            $this.attr('trackingID', $this.attr('trackingID') + trackRegEx);
        }
        i++;
    });
}

tracking($('#mainBanners a'), 'trackingID', 'MAINBANNER-_-BANNER[intBanner]-_-', $('#mainBanners a[trackingID]'), 0);
tracking($('#secBanners a'), 'trackingID', 'PROMOBANNER-_-BANNER[intBanner]-_-', $('#secBanners a[trackingID]'), 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you wanted?

Demo@[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/6vxe8qyj/2/)

```
$(".banner").each(function() {
    var title = this.title.replace(/\s+/g, "+");
    $(this).attr({
        "trackingid": "MAINBANNER-_-BANNER+" + title.slice(-1) + "-_-" + title
    });
});
```

P.S. please do your other checks, such as empty/undefined etc. as you please.

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you requested:

```
$('#mainBanners a.banner').attr('trackingID',function(i){
   return 'MAINBANNER-_-BANNER+' + (i+1)
});

$('#secBanners a.banner').attr('trackingID',function(i){
   return 'PROMOBANNER-_-BANNER+' + (i+1)
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6vxe8qyj/4/